# What is it meant by that Arrays are types?

Tags: java

I know that Arrays are special Objects in Java, and if I made an Array instantiated with Strings inside it, I would call the data type of my Array to be a String type, then where does this use of Array types term come in Java? I do not have the specific source on hand but I have heard and read this term used, so was wondering.

Comment: @Taschi, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#:~:text=Arrays,-Table%20of%20Contents&text=In%20the%20Java%20programming%20language,of%20type%20Object%20(%C2%A74.3. :  `In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1)`. That said, I also don't understand the question.

Comment: An array of X is insofar its own type as you can/have to differentiate it from X.

Comment: *I would call the data type of my Array to be a String type* No. The data type of an array is an array type. A `String[]` is a type of an array. It is not a `String` type. It is an `Object`. `Object arr = new String[] {"Hello", "World"};` - please clarify your question.

Answer (score 3):

For any type "T" in Java, there is an array type "T[]". Values of the array type are sequences of instances of T. You can also say that T is the type of the elements of the array type T[].

For example, `int` is a type. Therefore there is an int array type `int[]`. An example of a value of this type is `{2,7,8}`. The elements of this array are of type `int`.

> I would call the data type of my Array to be a String type

This would be sloppy use of the terminology: String is the type of the array elements. It's not the type of the array.